# Regular expression - issue with [,-?[0-9]+]* pattern

Tags: regex, character-class

This is my pattern:

```
^~[0-9]+@Y 1,710,-?[0-9]+[,-?[0-9]+]*\n$
```

For some reason it's match :`~01@Y 1,710,9,`

But not: `~01@Y 1,710,9`

I don't understand why it's need the last comma?

http://regex101.com/r/kP4pZ2/1

Comment: What do you want to match?

Comment: Do you really want to have `[` and `]` inside the last character class?

Comment: You probably want `(,-?[0-9]+)*`, not `[,-?[0-9]+]*`.

Comment: I need to mach strings like this: "~01@Y 1,710,1"   "~01@Y 1,710,0,-11" "~01@Y 1,710,-77"

Comment: @georg this is the answer!! simple..  thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is

```
[,-?[0-9]+]*
```

It will match `"~01@Y 1,710,9,"` or `"~01@Y 1,710,[9]"`

If you just want to define your expression match with comma, question mark, number or "-" at the end, you can try expression below:

```
^~[0-9]+@Y 1,710,-?[0-9]+[,?0-9-]*$
```